# UIView setHidden:NO like dropdown

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UIView which is initially hidden. I need to setHidden:NO (visible) with dropdown effect...

There's my simple code without effect

```
-(IBAction)btnAbrirDestaquesClick:(id)sender {
[self.viewDestaques setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: can you explain in detail, can you show how you initialized self.viewDestques

Comment: your view is in nib or you added it programatically

Comment: my view is in nib...I can hide and show ...but I need to show like an dropdown...

Comment: Could you explain exactly what it is you are trying to achieve? It is very unclear what it is that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler alternative to UIDynamicAnimator in iOS 7 is Spring Animation (a new and powerful UIView block animation), which can give you nice bouncing effect with damping and velocity:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
  delay:delay
  usingSpringWithDamping:damping
  initialSpringVelocity:velocity
  options:options animations:^{
    //Animations
     [self.viewDestaques setHidden:NO];

    }
  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //Completion Block
}];
```

Comment: which animation should I use for dropdown effect?

Comment: use UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to animate it try something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    self.viewDestaques.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,30);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.viewDestaques.frame  = CGRectMake(0, -30, 320,30);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
-(IBAction)btnAbrirDestaquesClick:(id)sender {
[self.viewDestaques setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]; //respeita o frame que eu setar, independentemente das constraints

[self.viewDestaques setFrame:CGRectMake(self.viewDestaques.frame.origin.x, self.viewDestaques.frame.origin.y, self.viewDestaques.frame.size.width, 0)];

[self.viewDestaques setHidden:NO];

while (self.viewDestaques.frame.size.height < self.frameViewDestaquesOriginal.size.height) {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
        [self.viewDestaques setFrame:CGRectMake(self.viewDestaques.frame.origin.x, self.viewDestaques.frame.origin.y, self.viewDestaques.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 10)];
    }completion: ^(BOOL completed){
    }];

   }
 }
```